# Why is document.cookie an empty string please

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, svelte, sapper

[I call Set-Cookie on the serverside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0743.png)

```
export async function post (req, res, next) {
  const jwtToken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImNocmlzLmNhcnJpbmd0b25AZ2xldy5pbyIsImlhdCI6MTU5OTA1NDcxNn0.NaEO1ywtCsD55oKb7JSaQbtzidySiy7Bld7Bs63_wuU'
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `jwtToken=${ jwtToken }; Max-Age=86400;`)
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ jwtToken }))
 }
```

- [jwtToken cookie shown on request & response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrqXC.png)

  Set-Cookie: jwtToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImNocmlzLmNhcnJpbmd0b25AZ2xldy5pbyIsImlhdCI6MTU5OTA1NDcxNn0.NaEO1ywtCsD55oKb7JSaQbtzidySiy7Bld7Bs63_wuU; Max-Age=86400;
- [Application > Cookies populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoNhM.png)
- [document.cookie empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys8O8.png)

I've tried the browsers Brave and Chrome, why is document.cookie an empty string in both browsers please?

Comment: were you able resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Cookie has `/api` path in Application > Cookies and is accessed from `/sign-in-with-token` path.

> If a cookie is set with path=/admin, it’s visible at pages /admin and /admin/something, but not at /home or /adminpage.

https://javascript.info/cookie#path

Maybe let's try to explicitly set the path to `/`:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `jwtToken=${ jwtToken }; Max-Age=86400; Path=/`)
```